# SML conversions to Haskell

Tags: haskell, sml

A few basic questions, for converting SML code to Haskell.
1) I am used to having local embedded expressions in SML code, for example test expressions, prints, etc. which functions local tests and output when the code is loaded (evaluated).
  In Haskell it seems that the only way to get results (evaluation) is to add code in a module, and then go to main in another module and add something to invoke and print results.

Is this right? in GHCi I can type expressions and see the results, but can this be automated?
Having to go to the top level main for each test evaluation seems inconvenient to me - maybe just need to shift my paradigm for laziness.

2) in SML I can do pattern matching and unification on a returned result, e.g.

> ```
> val myTag(x) = somefunct(a,b,c);
> ```

and get the value of x after a match.

Can I do something similar in Haskell easily, without writing separate extraction functions?

3) How do I do a constructor with a tuple argument, i.e. uncurried.
in SML:

> datatype Thing = Info of Int * Int;

but in Haskell, I tried;

> data Thing = Info ( Int Int)

which fails.  ("Int is applied to too many arguments in the type:A few Int Int")
The curried version works fine,

> data Thing = Info Int Int

but I wanted un-curried.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the other answers, I think I can provide a few more example and one recommendation.

```
data ThreeConstructors = MyTag Int | YourTag (String,Double) | HerTag [Bool]

someFunct :: Char -> Char -> Char -> ThreeConstructors

MyTag x = someFunct 'a' 'b' 'c'
```

This is like the "let MyTag x = someFunct a b c" examples, but it is a the top level of the module.

As you have noticed, Haskell's top level can defined commands but there is no way to automatically run any code merely because your module has been imported by another module.  This is entirely different from Scheme or SML.  In Scheme the file is interpreted as being executed form-by-form, but Haskell's top level is only declarations.  Thus Libraries cannot do normal things like run initialization code when loaded, they have to provide a "pleaseRunMe :: IO ()" kind of command to do any initialization.

As you point out this means running all the tests requires some boilerplate code to list them all.   You can look under hackage's [Testing](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html#cat%3atesting) group for libraries to help, such as [test-framework-th](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework-th).

Answer (score 5):

- This question is a bit unclear -- you're asking how to evaluate functions in Haskell?

If it is about inserting debug and tracing into pure code, this is typically only needed for debugging. To do this in Haskell, you can use `Debug.Trace.trace`, [in the base package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Debug-Trace.html).

If you're concerned about calling functions, Haskell programs evaluate from `main` downwards, in dependency order. In GHCi you can, however, import modules and call any top-level function you wish.

- You can return the original argument to a function, if you wish, by making it part of the function's result, e.g. with a tuple:

  `f x = (x, y)
        where y = g a b c`

Or do you mean to return either one value or another? Then using a tagged union (sum-type), such as `Either`:

```
f x = if x > 0 then Left x
                else Right (g a b c)
```

- How do I do a constructor with a tuple argument, i.e. uncurried in SML

Using the `(,)` constructor. E.g.

```
 data T = T (Int, Int)
```

though more Haskell-like would be:

```
 data T = T Int Bool
```

and those should probably be strict fields in practice:

```
 data T = T !Int !Bool
```

Comment: Yes, I suppose it could be debugging, but also any valid output.  I guess you summarized it in that everything is top-down, so the only way to change overall results is ot work at both top & bottom at the same time...

Comment: The second part you is different than what you reply - the RHS function returns a tagged datatype, and the expression then matches it to the Constructor (type), unifies on the LHS variable (x), and discards the Constructor. The result of the expression then is the extracted un-wrapped "x" value. No special unwrapping function is needed for each datatype, unification does it all.

Comment: SML doesn't do magic "unification" on values. Do you mean to name the LHS? If so, the '@' notation will work:   `f x@(_,y) = x`

Comment: @Guthrie: If I understand you correctly, you're asking about pattern matching in variable declaration, rather than in function arguments.  That works fine in Haskell: `let MyTag x = somefunct a b c in frob x`.  (Note that constructors need to begin with an uppercase letter, and that everything in Haskell is curried—you'll almost never see tuples used to bundle up arguments, unless the tuple is representing something [like a point].)

Answer (score 4):

1. [`Debug.Trace`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/Debug-Trace.html) allows you to print debug messages inline. However, since these functions use `unsafePerformIO`, they might behave in unexpected ways compared to a call-by-value language like SML.
2. I think the `@` syntax is what you're looking for here:

   ```
   data MyTag = MyTag Int Bool String

   someFunct :: MyTag -> (MyTag, Int, Bool, String)
   someFunct x@(MyTag a b c) = (x, a, b, c) -- x is bound to the entire argument
   ```
3. In Haskell, tuple types are separated by commas, e.g., `(t1, t2)`, so what you want is:

   ```
   data Thing = Info (Int, Int)
   ```

Comment: For the 2nd one, say that the function returns a datatype of two variants, a tagStr(s) or a tagInt(x), and I want to lookup something (perhaps a symbol table value or such) and return just one of those two types - and typecheck on the tag type, but then just use the returned (unwrapped) actual data value "x". The SML code just does as shown above, unifies on the myTag(x) thus setting the "x" value. I could of course get the return value, and then in an explicit second step unwrap it - but it works so nicely in SML I wondered what the best Haskell'ish idiom would be. Thanks.

Comment: guthrie, using e.g. the `Either` data type in Haskell. `Left String | Right Int` -- or another sum type.

Answer (score 1):

For #2, yes, Haskell's pattern matching does the same thing. Both `let` and `where` do pattern matching. You can do

```
let MyTag x = someFunct a b c
in ...
```

or

```
...
where MyTag x = someFunct a b c
```